# How do I get the XML request from WCF web service which located in DLL?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, web-services, soap

My project has DLL which implement Web Client functionality. How can I get XML request which is send to WCF service from that DLL? My call of DLL method looks like this:

```
LocalUser usr = DLLServiceProxy.GetUser("JohnS");
```

Comment: is it your service? can you add some code on it?

Comment: Serivce doesn't belong to me and client is 'build into' DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's for debugging purpose then you can check the svclog. If it's not for debugging purpose , then you will have to change the code in the dll so it returns that xml. Why would you want to have that xml?

More info on **[how to configure svclog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)**

Comment: Thank you for fast responce. It isn't for debugging, it's client /*paranoic*/ requirments. But thanks for link any way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to use some http sniffers, like Fiddler, [this](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/http_network_sniffer.html) one (not tested it by myself), or something else